# To how many users per second, 1 MB page can be served through 100 Mbps (12.5 MBps) uplink port of a dedicated server.

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, bandwidth, throughput, dedicated-server

To how many users per second, 1 MB page can be served through 100 Mbps (12.5 MBps) uplink port of a dedicated server.

I am planning to increase capacity of my dedicated server as my current server is not able to manage the load of my application.

Henceforth, I need to understand the uplink port connection offered by varied dedicated server providers.

In Amazon EC2 this is mentioned as Network Performance, which only providsions 10 Gigabit on its largest instances.

Pls guide.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, a 12.5MB/s connection is going to be able to serve a 1MB page to 12.5 users every second.

That said, are you absolutely sure it's the network throughput that's causing the problem, rather than a CPU or memory limit? In my experience, the network link is very rarely the bottleneck.

Bear in mind that a 1MB page will often compress to far less than that, assuming the server's compression is configured correctly. And unless you're genuinely seeing 12.5 new users every second, they will likely have a lot of the static assets (images, scripts, etc) cached either in their browser or by an upstream proxy, so they won't be requested every time.

If you really are just serving a 1MB page to a very high number of users rather than being bound by CPU, then you might more luck investigating a CDN (like [Cloudflare](http://www.cloudflare.com) or [Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)) than simply upgrading to a quicker link.

Comment: I am serving data through database on these pages. Should i upgrade to a better CPU & RAM .... to improve throughput and speed of serving pages.